# MATLAB using pdist to deal with Time series Clustering

Tags: matlab, time-series, cluster-analysis

I have a problem on time-series data clustering using MATLAB

I am trying to use the DTW library below to be my distance measure method
http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/16350-continuous-dynamic-time-warping

```
TimeData = csvread('testData10.csv',1,0)
Y = pdist(TimeData,@dtw_dist)
Z = linkage(Y,'complete')
dendrogram(Z)
```

I make a function to fit the format of 'pdist' distance function

```
function d2 = dtw_dist(XI,XJ)
    [dist,D,k,w,rw,tw] = dtw2(XI,XJ,0)
    d2 = dist
end
```

but I get the error message

```
Error using pdist (line 373)
Error evaluating distance function 'dtw_dist'.

Caused by:
    Error using  - 
    Matrix dimensions must agree.
```

I will be apericiate if anyone helps me

Thanks!

---2015.1.5 update ---

I change my funciton to call dtw to fit the format
and it works

```
function d2 = dtw_dist(XI,XJ)
    result =[];
    [m1,n1] = size(XI);
    [m2,n2] = size(XJ);
    for j=1:m2
        result = horzcat(result,dtw(XI,XJ(j,:)));
    end
    d2=result;    
end
```

Comment: It's hard to tell without having your data or that toolbox, but it looks like something goes wrong in the call to `dtw2`. I'd recommend checking whether you call that function correctly, e.g. by putting a breakpoint on that line and examining the values of `XI` and `XJ` and whether they match the sort of input the function expects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to tell without knowing what `dtw2` is. But here's one possible cause: When you call `pdist2` with a custom distance function, it should meet the following condition:

> A distance function must be of the form
>
> ```
>      function D2 = DISTFUN(ZI,ZJ)
> ```
>
> taking as arguments a 1-by-N vector ZI containing a single observation from X or Y, an M2-by-N matrix ZJ containing multiple observations from X or Y, and returning an M2-by-1 vector of distances D2, whose Jth element is the distance between the observations ZI and ZJ(J,:).

Check if `dtw2` fulfills that, and if not, modify it accordingly (or use a loop instead of `pdist2`).

Comment: Thank you very much!
I finally modify my function to call dtw to that role
and it works!